# How do I use UdpClient.BeginReceive with a Windows Form application (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, udp

My intention with the code below is to start looking (asynchronously) for a UDP datagram when my form opens.  When a datagram is received, all that I would like to do is call a procedure running on the main thread (passing the message received) and then re-start looking for another datagram.  Assuming the code is correct up to the point that the datagram shows up, how do I do the next two steps?  I'm really confused about cross-thread operations, delegates, etc.  Thanks.  Also, I'd like to stay with .Net 4.0.

```
Const RcvPort As Integer = 33900
Public RRWEndPoint As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(myIPaddr, RcvPort)
Public SiteEndPoint As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, RcvPort)
Public dgClient As UdpClient = New UdpClient(RRWEndPoint)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    dgClient.BeginReceive(AddressOf UDPRecv, Nothing)
End Sub

Public Sub UDPRecv(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim recvBytes As Byte() = dgClient.EndReceive(ar, SiteEndPoint)
    Dim recvMsg As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recvBytes)

    dgClient.BeginReceive(AddressOf UDPRecv, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your UDPRecv() method will run on an I/O completion thread.  Any attempt to update the UI from that thread is going to bomb your program.  You'll have to use the form's BeginInvoke() method to pass the string to a method that runs on the UI thread.  You will also have to deal with the socket getting closed when your program terminates, that requires catching the ObjectDisposedException that the EndReceive() call will throw.

So make it look like this:

```
Public Sub UDPRecv(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        '' Next statement will throw when the socket was closed
        Dim recvBytes As Byte() = dgClient.EndReceive(ar, SiteEndPoint)
        Dim recvMsg As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recvBytes)
        '' Pass the string to a method that runs on the UI thread
        Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf DataReceived), recvMsg)
        '' Continue receiving
        dgClient.BeginReceive(AddressOf UDPRecv, Nothing)
    Catch ex As ObjectDisposedException
        '' Socket was closed, do nothing
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DataReceived(recvMsg As String)
    '' This method runs on the UI thread
    '' etc...
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    '' Close the socket when the form is closed
    dgClient.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Hans.  I put the following where you have '' etc...:  Debug.WriteLine(recvMsg) and me.TextBox1.text=recvMsg.  The debug line shows the message but the textbox does not update.

Comment: My mistake.  It works great.  And it is simple.  Thanks again.